# Upscale an entire document, either in InDesign or in Acrobat pro?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-production, adobe-acrobat

I've designed a book in Indesign. I'd like to scale it up just a tad. Fonts are 11pts...more readable at 12pts or so...I'm not wanting to do an entire new layout. If not in indesign what about in Acrobat pro? It's a 6 x 9 book...so end output should be a little bit larger. say a 1/4 inch all the way around. Any advice...much appreciated. -1181

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say overwrite the PDF. This works but I am left with a series of pages, which are basically full images and thus can not edit. I have to edit in the smaller form and then go thru the script again for each page. Is there a way to upscale and have edit capability?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new document and place the original InDesign document in it and scale the pages to fit. This has to be done manually, but then you have a direct link to your source, in case you have to change something.

A bit quicker option is to export the book to PDF, at print quality but without downsampling image resolutions. Then, in InDesign go to View > Utilities > Scripts > Application > Samples > JavaScript > PlaceMultiplePDFs.jsx to place the pages automatically. They still need to be scaled manually. Just remember to overwrite the PDF and update the links in case you make any changes in the original document.

Comment: Which program are you referring to in the second solution? ...and how exactly do you scale the pages to fit...I assume in ID

Comment: In InDesign, I've updated the answer. You scale by dragging the corners: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/transforming-objects.html

Comment: Exactly how I'd handle it.. place one INDD inside another and scale.